# Char equal to char variables in C

Tags: c, string, char

I'm trying to make a char variable equal to a sequence of char variables in C. Any idea how I'd do this?

Example:

```
char s1 = "dunno";
char s2 = "what";
char s3;

s3 = s1,s2,s1; //equals dunnowhatdunno
```

Comment: No this isn't how that would work in C at all. The syntax for string declarations is invalid, and concatenation cannot be done via commas (`,`). Have you read any C tutorials or book?

Comment: char s1[]="dunno"; char s2[]="what"; char s3[99]; strcpy( s3 , s1 ); strcat(s3,s2); strcat(s3,s1); // buy a C book !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can't declare a multi-length char, chars are meant to hold only 1 character, so you must use a char array to store your values (or strings in C++):

```
char s1[] = "dunno";
char s2[] = "what";
```

We will store s3 as an empty char with 14 empty slots:

```
char s3[14];
```

Then, to concatenate two strings, you can use the strcat function (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/):

```
strcat(s3,s1);
strcat(s3,s2);
strcat(s3,s1);
```

This takes s1 and adds it to s3, and then s2 to s3, and finally s1 again to s3.

Here is the complete code:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main(void) {

    char s1[] = "dunno";
    char s2[] = "what";
    char s3[14];

    strcat(s3,s1);
    strcat(s3,s2);
    strcat(s3,s1);

    printf(s3);

    return 0;
}
```

The output of all 3 concatenations results in

```
dunnowhatdunno
```

EDIT: as @lurker said, it would be safer to first copy s1 to s3 to begin s3[] with "dunno" and then expand s3[].

Comment: Your variable, `s3`, isn't initialized before you use `strcat(s3, s1)` which is bad. You need `strcpy(s3, s1);` to start, then `strcat(s3, s2);` and then `strcat(s3, s1);`.